# Quickfix navigation not working properly

Tags: vimrc, quickfix, makeprg

I'm trying to lint my C files inside vim. I know that quickfix should help in this case. I found the following pc-lint file maintained by Craig Emery. I have this file in vim/vim80/compiler.

```
if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = "pc-lint"

if exists(":CompilerSet") != 2      " older Vim always used :setlocal
  command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
endif

CompilerSet makeprg=C:\Users\ahmes\PCLint\LIN.bat

CompilerSet errorformat=%A%f(%l\\,%c):\ %t%*[^\ ]\ %n:\ %m,%C%p_,%Z%s,%t%*[\ ]\ %n:\ %m\ (line\ %l\\,\ file\ %f)%*[^`]
```

When I open quickfix using `:copen` after running `:make %` and hit enter inside quickfix buffer, the current line is highlighted but it doesn't jump to the error location in the source file.

Another thing is that `:cp` and `:cn` just jump to the next/previous line in quickfix buffer and not to next/previous error.

I've read [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/815416/hitting-enter-in-the-quickfix-window-doesnt-work), but this is not my case as  is not mapped to anything in my vimrc.

How can I jump to error location inside the source file using quickfix?

**UPDATE**

I tried playing arround with pc-lint file. I've changed `errorformat` to be the following:

```
CompilerSet errorformat=%f:%m
```

After running `:make %`, the opened source file was closed and a new empty buffer was opened. Then I run `:copen`, and the quickfix list opened up and I could navigate between errors using `:cn` and `:cp`. When I hit enter on an error, the cursor moves to the empty new-opened buffer claiming in the status bar that it is the source file?

By the way, I'm working on a Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading and trials, I understood where is the problem.

PC-Lint (the linting tool I use) produces messages in specific format. For example, first comes the name of the file where the error is located `%f`, then comes the line number `%l`, then the message itself `%m`. This message format can be configured in PC-Lint.

On the other hand, quickfix should be configured so that the message format it expects is the same as the message format PC-Lint produces. This way, quickfix can know what is the file name, which line has the problem and so on.

The bottom line is, quickfix uses its `errorformat` to *interpret* the PC-Lint's messages and not to *display* them (as I thought before).

So the solution is to configure PC-Lint and Quickfix so that their message formats match.

[This file](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pub90/env-vim.lnt) is provided by Gimpel (PC-Lint developer) and it helps in clarifying the solution.